# Jest doesn't achieve to import module who imports modules using _moduleAliases

Tags: node.js, jestjs, package.json, module-alias

My module imports modules in that manner:

```
const { Item, Item1 } = require('@v2/helpers');
```

This is my package.json:

```
"_moduleAliases": { "@v2/helpers": "src/v2-helpers" }
```

Then in a test file I try to import a file who imports in the above mentioned manner and it gets failed because Jest cannot import those modules.

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@v2/helpers' from 'src/path/to/my-module.js'
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring)

- either in package.json

```json
{
  "": "... rest of the package.json",

  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@v2/helpers": "src/v2-helpers"
    }
  }
}
```

- or in the jest configuration `(jest.config.js)`

```js
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');
const {_moduleAliases} = require('./package.json');

module.exports = async () => {
  return {
    ...defaults,
    // rest of the configuration
    moduleNameMapper: _moduleAliases
  }
}
```

Comment: The first way works, the second doesn't I get validation error: Configuration option rootDir must be specified

Comment: Haven't tested it, probably have to add the defaults [as shown here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#options) (also updated the answer)